# using python socket online

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server, python-sockets

I have server and client codes, and I want someone out of my local network to send and recieve messages from my server, but he gets an error:
"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Server code:

```
import socket

LISTEN_PORT = 4444

def server():
    listening_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('', LISTEN_PORT)
    listening_sock.bind(server_address)
    listening_sock.listen(1)
    client_soc, client_address = listening_sock.accept()

    client_msg = client_soc.recv(1024).decode()
    print(client_msg)

    msg = 'server msg'
    print("sent")
    client_soc.sendall(msg.encode())


def main():
    server()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Cient code:

```
import socket

SERVER_IP = "<my local ip address>"
SERVER_PORT = 4444

def client():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    msg = input("Enter msg: ")
    sock.sendall(msg.encode())

    print(sock.recv(1024).decode())


def main():
    client()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried searching in stack overflow already but I couldn't find anything relevant

Comment: What exactly is the error? And if the client is outside of your network, you can't use the server's private IP address to access it. You'd need to use the public/external IP, and setup port forwarding on the router or something similar.

Comment: Do you know a simple way for setting up port forwarding?

Comment: If the client is external to your local network, then ya, you'd need to use the IP address of the external interface on the NAT device, then configure forwarding so it knows which internal host to send the traffic to.

Comment: And port forwarding is handled by your router (most likely). You'd need to go into it and configure it in there. You may need to find the documentation for your router, although it's often in the same general area as "firewall" settings, or settings that deal with "WAN".

Comment: ok thank youm i'll try

Comment: Correct firewall settings and possibly turning off anti-virus programs is always the first step in troubleshooting connections like these.

Comment: I'm reading your error again, and it's finding a computer with the given private address, it's just that that computer isn't expecting a connection. Does the remote client just happen to use the same private network address as your server? It's hard to say what the issue is because the error message seems to contradict your claim that the client is external to your local network, unless you just happen to have a computer with the same private IP address as your server on a separate network.